# Git merge issues after revert

Tags: git, github, merge

WE are facing a weird issue where our develop branch cannot merge to master branch with an explanation that there are no changes 
but if we inspect the code there are changes and differences between the master branch and the develop
it is worth mentioning that this happened after we reverted a master branch and merged the develop branch but this merge did not merge all the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Samit thanks for the link although it did not fix our issue it does point in the right direction.

We resolved the issue by doing "reset hard" and "push force" on the master branch to a time before the first incident, and by doing that we made the master branch ignore the new "branch history" we created.
afterward we successfully merged the develop branch.

Originally what we did not take into consideration when we reverted the master is that the revert we did, did not actually made the master branch "go back" to a state prior to our merge mistakes but rather created a new commits that are the opposite of the merge commit which made the master branch get ahead of the develop branch (commit-wise) and since the master branch is ahead of develop branch then there is nothing to merge from develop to master.

Hope this helps someone.